# vector Entry lookup in matlab

Tags: matlab

Given a vector *U* **n x 1** which contains the entries from **0,1,2,3** , I would like to create another vector *V* in char type such that the entry
    0 in *U* will be '0' in *V*
    1 in *U* will be '1' in *V*
    2 in *U* will be '12' in *V*
    3 in *U* will be '123' in *V*

What is the optimal way to do in matlab rather scanning each individual entry in the vector and then uses switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily define a set of rules and index into it.

```
rules={'0','1','12','123'};
out=rules(A+1)
```

In the above, `A` is the vector you have.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) to convert one element to the desired output and then use [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to apply this function to all of the inputs:

```
>> f = @(x) sprintf('%u', sum(10.^((x-1):-1:0) .* (1:x)));
>> x = 0:3

x =

     0     1     2     3

>> c = arrayfun(f, x, 'UniformOutput', 0)

c = 

    '0'    '1'    '12'    '123'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach is to create a cell array 'C' containing your 4 string values, then index the array with `U+1`:

```
>> C = {'0' '1' '12' '123'};  %# Cell array with 4 strings corresponding to 0..3
>> U = [0 1 2 3 2 1 0];       %# Sample U vector
>> V = C(U+1)                 %# Index C with U+1

V = 

    '0'    '1'    '12'    '123'    '12'    '1'    '0'
```

And if you want `V` to be a single character string instead of a cell array of strings, you can do this instead:

```
>> V = [C{U+1}]

V =

01121231210
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create a hashmap with the set of pairs you gave there. Every time you want to insert into V based on U, insert the value paired with the key that is the value of the entry of U into V. I.e. if U[0] = 2, then do V[0] = myMap.get(2), or whatever the MATLAB syntax is.

Comment: I dont want to scan the entries of U one by one , lookup the hashmap and then generate V. Looking for an vector/array function in matlab which does the requirement in single go.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a vectorized version which is idiomatic Matlab:

Nevertheless, this in effect does a linear scan 4 times. If you truly want more efficiency, write a C mex function.

```
V = cell(size(U));
V{U==0} = '0';
V{U==1} = '1';
V{U==2} = '12';
V{U==3} = '123';
```

**Edit:**

gnovice's solution is far superior. See above.

Comment: what if there were 10 entries? You really can't be entering all 10, right?